# Bulk modification of unique ids in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, scripting, identity

[This is a bit of an unusual problem, I know...]

What I need is a script that will change every unique id value to new one in our database.  The problem is that we have configuration tables that can be exported between instances of our software which is id-sensitive (clobbering existing ids). Years ago, we set up a "wide-enough" id gap between our development "standard configuration" and our client's instances, which is now *not* wide enough :( - e.g. we're getting id conflicts when clients import our standard configuration.

A SQL script to do the following is definitely the simplest/shortest-timeframe thing that we can do. e.g. fixing the code is far too complicated and error prone to consider. Note that we are not "eliminating" the problem here.  Just changing the gap from 1000's to 1000000's or more (the existing gap took 5 years to fill).

I believe the simplest solution would be to:

- change all our tables to UPDATE_CASCADE (none of them are - this will greatly simplify the script)
- create an identity table with the new lowest id that we want
- For each table, modify the id to the next one in the identity table (using identity insert modifier flags where necessary).  Perhaps after each table is processed, we could reset the identity table.
- turn off UPDATE_CASCADE, and delete the identity table.

I am seeking any (partial or full) scripts for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go with the code for SQL 2005.  It's huge, it's hacky, but it *will* work (except in the case where you have a primary key that is a composite of two other primary keys).

If someone can re-write this with MrTelly's faster id addition (which wouldn't require building sql from a cursor for each updated row), then I'll mark that as the accepted answer. (If I don't notice the new answer, upvote this - then I'll notice :))

```
BEGIN TRAN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @newLowId INT
SET @newLowId = 1000000

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)

--**** SELECT ALL TABLES WITH IDENTITY COLUMNS ****
DECLARE tables  SCROLL CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']', c.name
FROM sys.identity_columns c
INNER JOIN sys.objects t
    on c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.type_Desc = 'USER_TABLE'

OPEN tables

DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @IdColumn VARCHAR(100)

CREATE Table #IdTable(
  id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  s CHAR(1)
)

FETCH FIRST FROM tables
INTO @Table, @IdColumn

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT('
****************** '+@Table+' ******************
')
    --Reset the idtable to the 'low' id mark - remove this line if you want all records to have distinct ids across the database
    DELETE FROM #IdTable
    DBCC CHECKIDENT('#IdTable', RESEED, @newLowId)

    --**** GENERATE COLUMN SQL (for inserts and deletes - updating identities is not allowed) ****
    DECLARE tableColumns CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE '[' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + ']' = @Table
        AND column_name <> @IdColumn
    OPEN tableColumns
    DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(4000)
    SET @columns = ''
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableColumns INTO @columnName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @columns = @columns + @columnName
        FETCH NEXT FROM tableColumns INTO @columnName
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 SET @columns = @columns + ', '
    END

    CLOSE tableColumns
    DEALLOCATE tableColumns

    --**** GENERATE FOREIGN ROW UPDATE SQL ****
    DECLARE foreignkeys SCROLL CURSOR
    FOR 
    SELECT con.name, 
        '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(f.schema_id) + '].[' + f.name + ']' fTable, fc.column_name , 
        '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.name + ']' pTable,  pc.column_name 
    FROM sys.foreign_keys con
    INNER JOIN sysforeignkeys syscon
        ON con.object_id = syscon.constid
    INNER JOIN sys.objects f
        ON con.parent_object_id = f.object_id
    INNER JOIN information_schema.columns fc
        ON fc.table_schema = SCHEMA_NAME(f.schema_id)
        AND fc.table_name = f.name
        AND fc.ordinal_position = syscon.fkey

    INNER JOIN sys.objects p
        ON con.referenced_object_id = p.object_id
    INNER JOIN information_schema.columns pc
        ON pc.table_schema = SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id)
        AND pc.table_name = p.name
        AND pc.ordinal_position = syscon.rkey
    WHERE '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.name + ']' = @Table

    OPEN foreignkeys

    DECLARE @FKeyName VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @FTable VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @FColumn VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @PTable VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @PColumn VARCHAR(100)

    --**** RE-WRITE ALL IDS IN THE TABLE ****
    SET @sql='DECLARE tablerows CURSOR FOR
    SELECT CAST('+@IdColumn+' AS VARCHAR) FROM '+@Table+' ORDER BY '+@IdColumn
    PRINT(@sql)
    exec(@sql)

    OPEN tablerows
    DECLARE @rowid VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @id VARCHAR(100)


    FETCH NEXT FROM tablerows INTO @rowid
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --generate new id
        INSERT INTO #IdTable VALUES ('')
        SELECT @id = CAST(@@IDENTITY AS VARCHAR)
        IF @rowId <> @Id
        BEGIN
            PRINT('Modifying '+@Table+': changing '+@rowId+' to '+@id)
            SET @sql='SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @Table + ' ON
    INSERT INTO '+@Table+' ('+@IdColumn+','+@columns+') SELECT '+@id+','+@columns+' FROM '+@Table+' WHERE '+@IdColumn+'='+@rowId

            --Updating all foreign rows...
            FETCH FIRST FROM foreignkeys
            INTO @FKeyName, @FTable, @FColumn, @PTable, @PColumn

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @sql = @sql + '
    UPDATE '+@FTable+' SET '+@FColumn+'='+@id+' WHERE '+@FColumn+' ='+@rowId
                FETCH NEXT FROM foreignkeys
                INTO @FKeyName, @FTable, @FColumn, @PTable, @PColumn
            END
            SET @sql=@sql + '
    DELETE FROM '+@Table+' WHERE '+@IdColumn+'='+@rowId

            PRINT(@sql)
            exec(@sql)
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM tablerows INTO @rowid
    END

    CLOSE tablerows
    DEALLOCATE tablerows
    CLOSE foreignkeys
    DEALLOCATE foreignkeys

    --Revert to normal identity operation - update the identity to the latest id...
    DBCC CHECKIDENT(@Table, RESEED, @@IDENTITY)
    SET @sql='SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @Table + ' OFF'
    PRINT(@sql)
    exec(@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables
    INTO @Table, @IdColumn
END

CLOSE tables
DEALLOCATE tables

DROP TABLE #IdTable
--COMMIT
--ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately UPDATE_CASCADE doesn't exist in the world of Sql Server. I suggest for each table you to re-key you do the following (Pseudo Code)

```
BACKUP DATABASE
CHECK BACKUP WORKS!

FOR EACH TABLE TO BE RE-KEYED
   DROP ALL FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS, INDEXES ETC FROM TABLE

   SELECT ID + Number, ALL_OTHER_FIELDS INTO TEMP_TABLE FROM TABLE
   RENAME TABLE OLD_TABLE
   RENAME TEMP_TABLE TABLE

   FOR ALL TABLES REFERENCING THIS TABLE
       UPDATE FOREIGN_KEY_TABLE SET FK_ID = FK_ID + new number
   END FOR

   RE-APPLY FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS, INDEXES ETC FROM TABLE

END FOR
```

Check it all still works ...

This process could be automated through DMO/SMO objects, but depending on the number of tables involved I'd say using management studio to generate scripts that can then be edited is probably quicker. After all, you only need to do this once/5 years.

Comment: That's actually pretty awesome - just offset the id.  My solution cursors through all the rows and updates them.  Very tiresome and slow, but it's only a few thousand rows...

Comment: But note that it won't work because IDENTITY_INSERT only works for inserts, not updates.  Updates involves an ADD and a DELETE.

Comment: Changed the code to use SELECT INTO and not UPDATE - I had to do this myself, but I'd forgotten that gotcha.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use negative numbers for your standard configuration values and continue to use positive numbers for other things?

Comment: could do, but that would involve modifying the code, not using identities (it's the same code that will save client and our configuration), and the problem we have exists with current data.  We need to modify the database no matter what we do, so might as well go that route.